# Identifying missing imports in Groovy jar

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to create a jar file for a Groovy program I have written (BINSIC - an interpreter cum DSL that runs BASIC code: https://github.com/mcmenaminadrian/BINSIC).

I have a fundamental problem in that the code runs fine (if very slowly) on the development machine but fails on deployment (see below) - even on a box where I have installed a full Groovy installation. It looks like I'm failing to import something into the jar which is then called, though I don't know why that would fail when I have a full Groovy install. I have had the same problem with several different versions of Java (also using sdkman) activated.

What do I have to do to get the code to work on deployment? Does anyone know?

```
Setting groovy 3.0.2 as default.
lorraine@Kobani:~/Downloads$ java -jar binsic.jar test.bas
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class org.apache.groovy.jaxb.extensions.JaxbExtensions due to missing dependency javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.Java8.configureClassNode(Java8.java:458)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:274)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getMethods(ClassNode.java:396)
at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.AbstractExtensionMethodCache.scan(AbstractExtensionMethodCache.java:116)
at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.AbstractExtensionMethodCache.getMethods(AbstractExtensionMethodCache.java:97)
at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.AbstractExtensionMethodCache.getMethodsFromClassLoader(AbstractExtensionMethodCache.java:73)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute(StampedCommonCache.java:163)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:115)
at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.AbstractExtensionMethodCache.get(AbstractExtensionMethodCache.java:51)
at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroCallTransformingVisitor.findMacroMethods(MacroCallTransformingVisitor.java:119)
at org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroCallTransformingVisitor.visitMethodCallExpression(MacroCallTransformingVisitor.java:90)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:76)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:117)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:200)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:86)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:164)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.MethodCallTransformation.visit(MethodCallTransformation.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor.lambda$addPhaseOperationsForGlobalTransforms$4(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:336)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$ISourceUnitOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:880)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:650)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:627)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:389)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.lambda$parseClass$3(GroovyClassLoader.java:332)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute(StampedCommonCache.java:163)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:154)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:330)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:530)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:542)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:430)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:474)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.fromCache(IndyInterface.java:274)
at binsic.BinsicEngine.process(Binsic.groovy:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.fromCache(IndyInterface.java:274)
at binsic.Binsic.run(Binsic.groovy:81)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1029)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1027)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1010)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.runScript(InvokerHelper.java:442)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.fromCache(IndyInterface.java:274)
at binsic.Binsic.main(Binsic.groovy)
... 5 more
```

Comment: Java 11 no longer includes javax.xml and others that have been moved from SE to EE.  The Groovy distro includes the jaxb jar if you have already downloaded and installed Groovy.

Comment: Yes, I've sort of worked that bit out now after reading through some stuff. But how can I ensure that jar is packaged in my jar? I put an import line (import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext) in but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the root error message:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
>     Unable to load class org.apache.groovy.jaxb.extensions.JaxbExtensions
>       due to 
>       missing dependency javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
> ```

open site https://search.maven.org/

and search for full class name that s missing with prefix `fc:`

like this `fc:javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext`

https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext